# WPF Default Credential

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to access .net 2.0 Web Service from WPF. I generated the proxy using Visual Studio and also Credential of the proxy to Default Credentials.

I am getting 401 Unauthorized while accessing the web service. When I output the user name from the default credential it is empty, Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2):

found solution to my problem,

{proxy}.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
It works after setting this flag to true